# Muting 'Sound' instead of 'Music' in libgdx

Tags: audio, libgdx, mute, normalize

I'm developing a simple game using eclipse and libgdx.
Currently, I'm using 'Music' instead of 'Sound'  for sound effects for my game.
I made a button for muting all of the sound fx but having a problem when it comes to 'sound' instead of music.

Here's my current code:

```
public static Music jump;

public static void load() {
jump = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("data/jump.wav"));
}

public static void muteFX() {
lesgo.setVolume(0);

public static void normalizeFX() {
jump.setVolume(1f);


//'muteFX' and 'normalizeFX' to be called on different class
```

I wanted to change it to 'Sound' (the reason is I wanted it to be more responsive on fast clicks,) So it could be like this:

```
public static Sound jump;

public static void load() {
jump = Gdx.audio.newSound(Gdx.files.internal("data/jump.wav"));
}

/* here comes my problem, didn't know how to set mute and normal
volume for the jump sound. I know there is also a set volume method
to 'Sound' but really confused on the terms (long soundID, float volume)
Can someone make this clear to me on how to implement the long and soundID?
*/
```

I'm really new to libgdx, as well as in java. I researched many forums regarding this and still can't find a more clearer explanation.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks a lot in advance! =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick suggestion would be to use a global variable for sound

```
public static VOLUME = 1.0f;
```

The sound api allows you to play a sound at a certain volume, so what you could do is have all the sounds in your game play at that global value when needed.

```
jump.play(VOLUME);
```

this way, all your switch will do is change the float value of volume.

```
public static void muteFX(){
    VOLUME = 0.0f;
}
public static void normalizeFX(){
    VOLUME = 1.0f;
}
```

It would be in your best interest to not use the Music class for sound effects due to memory constraints.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for answering, however, tried this one but I wonder why I can't mute the sound even if I run/pressed the muteFX() method. Still it uses the "VOLUME = 1.0f" when it is called to play. My sound is just a sound effect(1 second duration) and not in loop.

Comment: when you call play you are passing in VOLUME right? sound.play(VOLUME)? try logging VOLUME during runtime, Gdx.app.log("APP", "My Volume : "+VOLUME);

Comment: Solved my problem now! I learned a lot from this answer. Thanks so much! The problem to my codes for volume is that, it is not logged during runtime. I returned the volume from my runtime game class with 'VOLUME = 0.0f' to declare it on the mute button that solved it. Thanks a lot! =)

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation it states that the id is returned when play() or loop() methods succeed. This might not be convenient depending what are you trying to achieve. Basicly you can get the id and use it with something similar to this:

```
long id = sound.play(1.0f); // play new sound and keep handle for further manipulation
sound.stop(id);             // stops the sound instance immediately
sound.setPitch(id, 2);      // increases the pitch to 2x the original pitch
```

When I wanted to have a button Volume OFF and Volume ON I had a global variable which I would check before I play the sound somethign similar to this:

In my main Game Class:

```
public static boolean soundEnabled;
```

Whenever I wanted to play sound.

```
if (MyMainClass.soundEnabled)
sound.play();
```

In case you want any other control of the sound then inevetably you need to get the sound's id.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation for the soundID and long. You're right, it will not be convenient to use it on my case. Used a global variable and it's all working now. Thanks a lot!